# Dynamic BizTalk Port

Tags: biztalk

I am attempting to define the attributes of a dynamic WCF-WebHttp Send Port at run time.

I want to hit the end point with a specific token:

The code in my message assignment shape has ballooned into this:

The end point is a GET method on Traxo's REST API. https://api.traxo.com/v2/me

```
Token = "1234TOKEN1234";

Input2 = Input;

DYNAMIC_OAUTH_PORT(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address)="https://api.traxo.com/v2/me";
DYNAMIC_OAUTH_PORT(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.TransportType) = "WCF-WebHttp";

Input2(WCF.BindingType)="WCF-WebHttp";
Input2(WCF.Action)="https://api.traxo.com/v2/me";
Input2(WCF.HttpHeaders)= "Content-Type: application/json" + "\r\n" + "Authorization: Bearer " + Token + "\r\n";
Input2(WCF.SuppressMessageBodyForHttpVerbs)="GET"; 
Input2(WCF.SecurityMode)="Transport"; 
Input2(WCF.MessageClientCredentialType)="Transport"; 
Input2(WCF.HttpMethodAndUrl)="GET";
Input2(WCF.TransportClientCredentialType)="Windows";
```

I am running into the following error:

System.ArgumentException: The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
Parameter name: via
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelFactory`1.ValidateScheme(Uri via)

I have tried to accurately as possible, dynamically mimic a static send port definition that is working correctly.

Comment: Have you tried http?  SecurityMode = Transport means TLS/SSL.  While the content is tunneled by TLS, it's still http protocol.

Comment: I will amend the code and give it a go.

Comment: Give it a try.  It's one of this things I've done prolly a dozen times, but it's so trivial, I don't remember :(.

Comment: I commented out the following lines from the above: I received the same error:

//Input2(WCF.SecurityMode)="Transport"; 

//Input2(WCF.MessageClientCredentialType)="Transport";

Comment: Its the receive side of the dynamic port that's failing. The message is successfully sent.

Comment: Ok, that can't be right.  That error would only happen at initialization, before even trying to contact the endpoint.

Comment: Hello, I log to a file in an expression shape after the message is sent. And the comment is logged.

Comment: Ah, if the Expression Shape is between the Send and Receive, sure, it's executed independently from the Send so you'll see that message even though the Port is failing.  It's Async.

Comment: Hello, I have dumped the bindings from the working static port to a file. Am I correct in assuming the binding values should correspond to WCF.<properties> ?

Comment: yes....at least I can't think of an instance where they would be different.

Comment: I used the bindings dump to construct a set of expressions to set each WCF attribute exactly as the static port was configured and the error is still present?

Answer (score 0):

What I eventually did was define a static port, and used a custom pipeline component that used the execute method to update the message properties.